# How do I fix a page refresh that causes the page to be blank on initial load for the same duration as refresh interval?

Tags: javascript, partial-page-refresh

I would like to create a page that updates its content at a regular interval (e.g. every 10 seconds).

I have the following code which works, but it also results in the page being blank for 10 seconds upon the initial page load.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>  
            window.setInterval("refreshDiv()", 10000);  
            function refreshDiv() {   
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<iframe src='website' style='width:100%; height:100%;'></iframe>";  
            }  
        </script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="staticBlock">  
            text
        </div>
        <div id="test" style="width:100%; height:100%; border:1px solid #000;">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I have the content load instantaneously, and also refresh it every 10 seconds using this code?

Comment: Call refreshDiv()? Take Davids advice... this is not headed in a good direction.

Comment: TIL that `window.setInterval("refreshDiv()", 10000);` actually works, Javascript is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Call `refreshDiv()` after it's declared.

```
<script>  
    window.setInterval("refreshDiv()", 10000);  
    function refreshDiv(){   
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<iframe src='website' style='width:100%; height:100%;'></iframe> ";  
    }  
    refreshDiv();
</script>
```

Comment: You know, that makes a lot of sense but for some reason it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set `refreshDiv` to be called after the site has loaded.

```
<script>  
    window.setInterval("refreshDiv()", 10000);  
    function refreshDiv(){   
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<iframe src='website' style='width:100%; height:100%;'></iframe> ";  
    }  
    window.addEventListener('load', refreshDiv);
</script>
```

Comment: Will this work as a solution even though the initial page content and the content to be refreshed are the same?

Comment: @user3846962 I'm not quite sure what you mean, but if you're loading the same content into the iframe it will not create an infinite loop as the browser prevents it.

Comment: Also if the URL does not contain cache control headers, you'd need to add a random string too: "...src='website?rnd="+Math.random()+"'..."

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Ajax, A better idea is to wrap `function refreshDiv()` in a `()`, like this:

```
<script>
    window.setInterval(refreshDiv, 10000); // You can also directly point to the function
    (function refreshDiv(){
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<iframe src='website' style='width:100%; height:100%;'></iframe> ";  
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: How might I go about using Ajax to accomplish this?

Comment: Well, basically you'd want to write a server-sided script also, but all you have to do is requesting the remote content and replace the page content. - This is very armature, I advice using pre-written scripts on the net. Look them up on Google.